# Load partial into div from post

Tags: asp.net-mvc

The issue I am having is that I have a partial that has a form. The requirements are that the search is in the url so the user can email their search and others can view what they found. In order to put the search criteria in the url I am using a post to do the search and get back a view and display it.

Right now I have my main index page that has a onchange event that is bound to a drop down. When it detects a change it loads the partial that relates to the drop down value. In this view I have a button to search which puts the search data into the url and reloads the page.

My issue is how can I go from the index which has the drop down, to the partial which loads the search options to the result that has the search results.

Comment: Someone upvoted my question and I just figured it out. Basically when I search and post the values in the url I had to put an if in my index page and then load the html of the div id with the partial that was returned.